# Why do we even have a "Test" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Even the description of the [test tag](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/tags/test/info) says not to use it, yet there are 40+ questions with this tag. Many look like they are from newbie users that aren't reading tag descriptions anyway, though it looks like at least one more experienced user has used it as well. Can't we just kill it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent this tag from showing up again, I've blocked the [test](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test) tag:

[image: Testing the 'test' tag.]

Answer (score 1):

The honest answer is **we don't**.

But removing a tag is not so easily done. Each question has to have it removed and still be properly tagged (even if it's closed). Simply put a tag that has questions on it can't be removed.

Once it's removed from all questions, then we can go about blacklisting it. And to blacklist it, we have to get Stack Exchange staff involved. So we really only want to do this once the legwork is done. They won't blacklist it if it is in use, so we really need our ducks crossed and our eyes in a row before we contact them. (Although they have keen eyes and will have probably seen this post before it happens, even if they don't comment.)

Comment: Ok. I started on the legwork and reached my cap for pending edits. Anyone else can feel free to jump in as well.

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/GVMhZwYv8U5NK/giphy.gif

Comment: Unfortunately many of my edits got rejected. I included a link to this meta post in most of my edit comments but a couple reviewers seemed to just reject it without looking :(

Comment: e.g. https://sqa.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/19707

Comment: Filled my queue again. Hopefully reviewers will at least look at this before rejecting this time...

Comment: Cool, thanks for plowing through them. Looks like there are 6 remaining--I have pending edits on 5 and a flag for deletion on 1. See https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test